# Reducing Foreach loops?

Tags: php

It put the data into $itemsData[] array from modelItem::find() loop

When I outputing the data, I have to do foreach twice, how to reduce into 1 foreach loop?

```
$itemsData = array();
foreach ($_SESSION['Cart'] as $optionid => $OptionData) {
    $item = modelItem::find('id = :item_id', array('item_id' => $OptionData['item_id']));
    $itemsData[] = $item;
}


// How to put this in into single foreach?
foreach ($itemsData as $items) {
     foreach($items as $item) {
         echo $item->name;
     }
 }



Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => modelItem Object
                (
                    [id] => 319
                    [name] => xxxxxx xxxxxx
                    [category_id] => 434
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => modelItem Object
                (
                    [id] => 320
                    [name] => xxx & xxxx xxxxx
                    [category_id] => 424
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: *Why* do you want to put it in a single `foreach`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you need to use foreach twice, is because mysql itself, returns a set. "modelItem::find" returns an array in turn.

When you do `$itemsData[] = $item;` you append an array. Resulting in a nested array.

A simple solution would be to change:

```
$item = modelItem::find('id = :item_id', array('item_id' => $OptionData['item_id']));
foreach($item as $x)
    $itemsData[] = $x;
```

But this still gives you a foreach, so you might wanna try:

```
$item = modelItem::find('id = :item_id', array('item_id' => $OptionData['item_id']));
$itemsData=array_merge($itemsData, $item);
```

In this second example you can even pass `modelItem::find()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

right code is

```
foreach ($_SESSION['Cart'] as $optionid => $OptionData) {
   $item = modelItem::find('id = :item_id', array('item_id' => $OptionData['item_id']));
   if(!empty($item)){
     $item = array_shift($item);
     echo $item->name;
   }
}
```

What it basically does is, assumes that the $item array has only one element and uses this element via shift as the element to echo. It is allways good to know PHP's  array functions by heart. Take a look at

http://php.net/manual/de/ref.array.php

See working code

http://codepad.org/lyDlutFm

for an example

Regards

Answer (score -1):

Seems to me you can already do one loop:

```
foreach ($itemsData as $item) {
     echo $item->name;
}
```

Comment: @halfdan he has nested arrays, the solution proposed will not work.

Comment: you get my +1 because its not so bad, but anyways it wouldn't work because `$item` is an array

Comment: @user622378 Yes, that *will* work, if the `$item` you put in the array is in fact an object with a (accessible) name property. You would see why this doesn't work in your case if you'd debug the `$itemsData`/`$item` variables, and see it's not an object you're putting in there. I cannot know what variable is returned, since I don't know what the `modelItem::find` function returns, I just copied what you already specified in your question: `echo $item->name`

Comment: @Peter, exactly! You saw the code, just copied a chunk out and said `here it is`. Next time consider reading the question in it's entirety. This will not work. you can clearly see he has nested arrays.

Comment: With the updated question, yes. Initially, the debug info wasn't in his question.